# Rounded corners for QMenu in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to override the `paintEvent()` of `QMenu` to make it have rounded corners.

The context menu should look something like this.

[image]

Here is the code I have tried But nothing appears:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
import sys


class Example(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Context menu')
        self.show()

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        cmenu = AddContextMenu(self)

        newAct = cmenu.addAction("New")
        openAct = cmenu.addAction("Open")
        quitAct = cmenu.addAction("Quit")
        action = cmenu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()))


class AddContextMenu(QtWidgets.QMenu):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddContextMenu, self).__init__()
        self.painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        self.setMinimumSize(150, 200)

        self.pen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red)
        #self.setStyleSheet('color:white; background:gray; border-radius:4px; border:2px solid white;')

    def paintEvent(self, event) -> None:
        self.pen.setWidth(2)

        self.painter.setPen(self.pen)
        self.painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtCore.Qt.blue))
        self.painter.drawRoundedRect(10, 10, 100, 100, 4.0, 4.0)
        self.update()
        #self.repaint()
        #super(AddContextMenu, self).paintEvent(event)

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note: setting a style sheet doesn't work for me:

this is what I get when using the style sheet It isn't completely rounded.

[image]

This is the paintEvent after @musicamante suggestion(This is just for him/her to check)

```
    def paintEvent(self, event) -> None:
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)

        #self.pen.setColor(QtCore.Qt.white)
        #painter.setFont(QtGui.QFont("times", 22))
        #painter.setPen(self.pen)
        #painter.drawText(QtCore.QPointF(0, 0), 'Hello')

        self.pen.setColor(QtCore.Qt.red)
        painter.setPen(self.pen)
        painter.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.gray)
        painter.drawRoundedRect(self.rect(), 20.0, 20.0)
```

and in the init()

```
self.pen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red)
self.pen.setWidth(2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the border radius in the stylesheet for a *top level widget* (a widget that has its own "window") is not enough.

While the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65576117/2001654) proposed by Christian Karcher is fine, two important considerations are required:

1. The system *must* support compositing; while this is true for most modern OSes, at least on Linux there is the possibility that even an up-to-date system does *not* support it by choice (I disabled on my computer); if that's the case, setting the `WA_TranslucentBackground` attribute will not work.
2. The `FramelessWindowHint` should **not** be set on Linux, as it may lead to problems with the window manager, so it should be set only after ensuring that the OS requires it (Windows).

In light of that, using [`setMask()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setMask-1) is the correct fix whenever compositing is not supported, and this has to happen within the `resizeEvent()`. Do note that masking is *bitmap* based, and antialiasing is *not* supported, so rounded borders are sometimes a bit ugly depending on the border radius.

Also, since you want custom colors, using stylesheets is mandatory, as custom painting of a QMenu is **really** hard to achieve.

```
class AddContextMenu(QtWidgets.QMenu):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddContextMenu, self).__init__()
        self.setMinimumSize(150, 200)
        self.radius = 4
        self.setStyleSheet('''
            QMenu {{
                background: blue;
                border: 2px solid red;
                border-radius: {radius}px;
            }}
            QMenu::item {{
                color: white;
            }}
            QMenu::item:selected {{
                color: red;
            }}
        '''.format(radius=self.radius))

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        # the rectangle must be translated and adjusted by 1 pixel in order to 
        # correctly map the rounded shape
        rect = QtCore.QRectF(self.rect()).adjusted(.5, .5, -1.5, -1.5)
        path.addRoundedRect(rect, self.radius, self.radius)
        # QRegion is bitmap based, so the returned QPolygonF (which uses float
        # values must be transformed to an integer based QPolygon
        region = QtGui.QRegion(path.toFillPolygon(QtGui.QTransform()).toPolygon())
        self.setMask(region)
```

Some side notes about your paintEvent implementation, not necessary in this specific case for the above reason, but still important (some points are related to portions of code that have been commented, but the fact that you *tried* them makes worth mentioning those aspects):

1. The QPainter used for a widget must **never** be instanciated outside a `paintEvent()`: creating the instance in the `__init__` as you did is a serious error and might even lead to crash. The painter can only be created when the paintEvent is received, and shall *never* be reused. This clearly makes useless to set it as an instance attribute (`self.painter`), since there's no actual reason to access it after the paint event.
2. If the pen width is always the same, then just set it in the constructor (`self.pen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red, 2)`), continuously setting it in the paintEvent is useless.
3. QPen and QBrush can directly accept Qt global colors, so there's no need to create a QBrush instance as the painter will automatically (internally and fastly) set it: `self.painter.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.blue)`.
4. `self.update()` should **never** be called within a paintEvent (and not even `self.repaint()` should). The result in undefined and possibly dangerous.
5. If you do some manual painting with a QPainter and *then* call the super paintEvent, the result is most likely that everything painted before will be hidden; as a general rule, the base implementation should be called *first*, then any other custom painting should happen *after* (in this case it obviously won't work, as you'll be painting a filled rounded rect, making the menu items invisible).

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your answer. After your suggestions, I attempted to override the paint method and it works, but the problem is that though I didn't call the super in the paintEvent there is a rectangle behind the rounded Rect. Do you know why that would be happening?

Comment: I cannot know what is happening, as I don't know how you implemented it, but I stand by my warning: custom painting of QMenu is *very* hard to correctly achieve and it's normally better to avoid it. It is a *really* complex widget, and even if you might think that it's fine to do custom painting for simple cases, you'll soon find out that it's not as easy as it seems, as you should need to consider a lot of aspects, including but not limited to: font metrics, text elision and mnemonics, icon and control placement, layout, control rectangles of items.

Comment: I am not going to use it. I just wanted to know why that happens. I'll add an update to the question for you to check.

Comment: Is the update is your recent editing, and the "rectangle behind" is similar to those shown in the stylesheet example screenshot? If that's so, have you also implemented the `resizeEvent` with the correct radius? Please, when you edit your post and add some more code, add some context to that, otherwise it won't be clear what that new code comes from.

Comment: No, I have not reimplemented the `resizeEvent` can you shed some light on this. As for the question, I'll edit it to add more clarity

Comment: @JacksonPro please read more carefully my answer, try to understand what its code does and read the documentation for the functions used if you don't know them yet. If you don't use `setMask()` (which **must** be called in the resizeEvent, as it needs to use the *current* size) the widget will always have a rectangular shape, so the standard QWidget background will always be painted and visible under your painting functions.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot comment on the paintEvent functionality, but it is possible to implement rounded corners using style-sheets. Some qmenu attributes have to be modified in order to disable the default rectangle in the background, which gave you the unwanted result.

Here is a modified version of your Example using style-sheets + custom flags (no frame + transparent background):

[image]

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
import os
import sys


class Example(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Context menu')
        self.show()

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        cmenu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
        # disable default frame and background
        if os.name == "nt":
            # This is only necessary for Windows
            cmenu.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        cmenu.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        # set stylesheet, add some padding to avoid overlap of selection with rounded corner
        cmenu.setStyleSheet("""
            QMenu{
                  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
                  border-radius: 20px;
            }
            QMenu::item {
                    background-color: transparent;
                    padding:3px 20px;
                    margin:5px 10px;
            }
            QMenu::item:selected { background-color: gray; }
        """)

        newAct = cmenu.addAction("New")
        openAct = cmenu.addAction("Open")
        quitAct = cmenu.addAction("Quit")
        action = cmenu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()))

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It should be pointed out that the `FramelessWindowHint` is only necessary for Windows, and that the `WA_TranslucentBackground` attribute only works when there is a window manager that supports composition.

Comment: I was not aware that IOs and other OSes would not require the FramelessWindowHint, thanks for the comment @musicamante As for the window manager remark, I am much too dumb for that, I do not even know what you mean by by "window manager". Are you talking about https://doc.qt.io/QtApplicationManager/qml-qtapplicationmanager-systemui-windowmanager.html? If so, shouldn't this be the same across all pyqt distributions?

Comment: No, I'm talking about Linux: the graphic server must support ARGB and the window manager (which is responsible of *managing* the windows, as in stacking, visibility, geometry, etc) must support compositing, which is what allows transparency effects, including windows with antialiased shapes. Do note that the `FramelessWindowHint` should *not* be set for Linux (I don't know if it's necessary for macOS).

Comment: @musicamante thanks for the clarification! For Mac it's not necessary either, I checked that upon your first comment.

Comment: @musicamante is this the best way of achieving the rounded border or is there any other method for achieving this?

Comment: @JacksonPro it's possibly the best *assuming* that the OS supports it. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented round corners menu using `QListWidget` and `QWidget`. You can download the code in https://github.com/zhiyiYo/PyQt-Fluent-Widgets/blob/master/examples/menu/demo.py.
[image]